# improve performance of selecting a subset of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with 10000s of columns and I want to select a subset of it. What I am using is

```
newdf = df[[column for column in df if "exclude_me" is not in column]]
```

but this takes hours to calculate. Is there a faster workaround like converting it to a matrix or using numpy?

Comment: uh, this really shouldn't take hours.

Comment: And `pandas` **already uses `numpy` under the hood.

Comment: actually I just stopped the calculation its not 10000s its 470000 columns and 70 rows....

Comment: Still, `470000` columns shouldn't take *hours*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, using the position index with iloc and not the names is much faster

```
newdf= df.iloc[:,[ind for ind,col in enumerate(df.columns) if "exclude_me" not in col]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information or a data set to run, it's a guessing game whether the issue originates from collecting the column names or from slicing the DataFrame. Since slicing should be fast with pandas, I'd look at the column calculation first.

This should give you the same result but might be faster for a large amount of columns:

`columns = list(val for val in my_dataframe.columns.values if "exclude_me" is not in val)
newdf = df[columns]`

Comment: Huh? Why would wrapping a generator expression in `list` be *faster* than a list-comprehension???

Comment: I tried this ine as well it is the slicing... Even if I only remove one column it takes forever. Deepcopy works fine

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The difference in my approach compared to the OP is iterating over dataframe.columns.values instead of iterating over the dataframe itself. Of course, you can also use a list comprehension (or just pass a generator to the dataframe - though I don't know if pandas can handle that).

Comment: Iterating over a data-frame *iterates over the column names* You've merely added two unecessary attribute acceses, and used `list(<generator-expression>)`, which will always be slower than the equivalent `[<list-comprehension>]` which is what the OP has